# Binning continuous variable then visualizing it with ggplot does not reproduce example in textbook?

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning, continuous

Given "diamonds" [dataset](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/diamonds.html) in tidyverse,
and filtering it as per [ch.7](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/exploratory-data-analysis.html#two-continuous-variables) in "R for Data Science":

`smaller <- diamonds %>% filter(carat < 3)`,

I expect

```
ggplot(data = smaller, mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
+   geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(group = cut_width(carat, 0.1)))
```

to return
[price vs carat (binned)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcQUr.png),
but instead see this
[returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZc88.png).

Why is this? Is it because of a change in ggplot2, or is it another reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. With the release of `ggplot2 3.3.0` bi-directional geoms and stats have been introduced, which also result in a kind of *direction determination* by `ggplot2`. See [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/):

For this reason you have to add `orientation=x` to get the plot from R4DS:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

smaller <- diamonds %>% filter(carat < 3)

ggplot(data = smaller, mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(group = cut_width(carat, 0.1)), orientation = "x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>